# What's a word meaning a never-ending source?

Tags: single-word-requests

Insatiable means can never be satisfied, sort of like a sink that can never be filled.

Whats the word for a never-ending source? For example:

> My source of funding is [Missing word goes here].

While we are at it, what word should I have used in place of opposite?.
(Since the opposite of insatiable is of course satiable).

Comment: Your second sentence is right for the title. Please edit the title.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Inexhaustible* (as in "an inexhaustible supply") is the *converse* of insatiable.

Comment: Is complement preferred to converse as per Wallaces answer?

Comment: @artfullyContrived I think Wallace's word (*complement*) is better than *converse*, so I've change my answer accordingly.

Comment: No it isn't. *Inexhaustible* is the converse of *exhaustible*. Thus it means there's so much of something that it will never run out, whereas *insatiable* means "incapable of being satiated" *(satisfied)*. With the implication that no amount of whatever is being consumed will be enough to satisfy, even an inexhaustible supply.

Comment: When I was in High School math I was taught that a "converse" is what you get by switching the condition and the conclusion of a proposition, like if we start with A implies B then the converse is B implies A. Like, if we start with, "All Ruritanians are ugly", the converse would be "All ugly people are Ruritanians". Maybe that's a math-specific definition.

Comment: Yes, that's a math & logic specific definition.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. What word then describes the relationship between inexhaustible and insatiable?

Comment: @artfullyContrived: I'd say the relationship is indirectly contrasting, or something like that. The primary connection is that one word quantifies the *appetite for consumption*, the other quantifies the *amount available to be consumed*, so they're only connected via the concept of consumption in the first place. I agree you can say *eat* and *be eaten* are "opposites", but so are *eat* and *starve*. There's only an indirect connection between *be eaten* and *starve*.

Answer (score 2):

The usual word to "use in place of opposite" when speaking of words is *[antonym](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antonym)*, "A word which has the opposite meaning of another, although not necessarily in all its senses."

Regarding an antonym of insatiable, *[satiable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/satiable)* is indeed a word, and per wiktionary it means

> Capable of being sated, satisfiable. (eg) The god's demand for blood was satiable only by the sacrifice of a virgin.

However, *satiable* does not fit appropriately into your example sentence; instead try a word like *bottomless*, *endless*, *unfathomed*, *bountiful*, or *overflowing* or previously-suggested *inexhaustible* if you mean that your funding will never run out.

Comment: The questioner is not looking for a synonym of *opposite*.  He is looking for a word that describes the relationship between *insatiable* and *inexhaustible*.

Comment: @jwpat Yes, Pitarou got it right.

Answer (score 1):

The answers to your two questions are "never-ending" and "converse", respectively.

Comment: I've combined the best part of your answer (*converse*) with the best part of mine (*inexhaustible*).  Apologies for stealing your thunder, but it's a brutal dog eat dog world here on StackExchange.

Comment: @davidwallace. You still get my up vote though.

Answer (score 0):

**Inexhaustible**: cannot be entirely consumed or used up.

> an inexhaustible supply of coal

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're fishing for an adjective, but a noun might also fill the bill. At least, in Physics, the term "reservoir" (as in "heat reservoir") is often used in this sense of "an inexhaustible source".

Answer (score 0):

If **insatiable** means "I am unable to be satisfied", then the *converse* would be "Things are unable to satisfy me".  Those things might be described as **inadequate**.  If you're looking for a never ending source, then you're looking for the *counterpart* or *complement* to something insatiable.

I would further add that insatiability has an element of excess. You can't get enough. So the counterpart would have to have a similar extreme, being more than you need, not simply all that you need.

I also think perfectly insatiable and never-ending, can't exist together, much like immovable objects and unstoppable forces.

Answer (score 0):

You could describe your source of funding as *[infinite](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/infinite?q=infinite)*:

> limitless or endless in space, extent, or size; impossible to measure or calculate